# Content-Disposition is always null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I've a got a function in my web api 2.0 to download a file but hadn't tried it in a while and only discovered yesterday that it was no longer working. I've partially fixed the issue with `createObjectURL` but one thing I've noticed is that while the `Content-Disposition` is set in my web api:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    var filename = this.Document.GetFilename();
    var mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);
    
    response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(this.Document.ToData()));     
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = this.Document.Data.Length;     
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mimeType);

    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = filename
    };

    return Task.FromResult(response);
}
```

Yet when I check it in `JavaScript`, it always null from the response header:

```
success: function (blob, status, xhr) {
   var filename = "";
   var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
   ...
}
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks.

**UPDATE-1:**

The content disposition appears to be returned when I check the response in the `Network` section of the browser but when I call `xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()` or `xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');`, it is not returned by either function calls as you can see in the snapshot below:

[image]

Comment: Can you check the request in browser DevTools? What is the value of the reponse header there?

Comment: @Markus I've checked and added an updated with snapshot to the question and it appears to be returned but it's not returning me the Content-Disposition when I call the xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() or xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');

Comment: @Thierry I am also facing the same problem. Did you find any solution to this? I am facing this with jquery.

Comment: @Shiv The answer I posted is what caused my problem, so can't really provide you with more help than what I said in the answer. Sorry

Comment: I found the solution to this issue, posting my answer @Thierry

Answer (score 1):

From server side, please set this header in response `"Access-Control-Expose-Headers”` with value `“*”` to make all headers in response to be read by frontend script. Or just set `“Content-Disposition”` for this case, instead of *, to only allow reading value of content-disposition header by frontend script.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the problem and it was of my own doing unfortunately!!

I had the following in my ajax request:

```
xhrFields: {
    responseType: 'blob' 
}
```

but then I introduced credentials support and introduce this

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
}
```

but I didn't spot this until this morning when I realized I stupidly declared as above clearly i.e. 2 statements, thus, overwriting the `responseType: 'blob'` setting when I should have declared it as:

```
xhrFields: {
    responseType: 'blob',
    withCredentials: true
}
```